# How complex can racism get?

Tags: society, fantasy-races, social-norms

In my world, there are humans and a variety of fantasy races. Of course, due to instinct, there is going to be racism and forms of discrimination. For realism, and just tired of the usual fantasy racism tropes, I was planning on making humans still be racist towards other humans while also hating fantasy races.

From this it also gave me the idea of making the fantasy races themselves also be racist to their minorities of their own species and sub-species. In the end, how complex can racism and hate be, or is it just a mob mentality with little to no thinking or logic, even if the logic is delusional?

Comment: It's your world so you can decide how complex in the racism in your world will be. If you can construct a sufficiently complex racism you can create a world that will have said complex racism. We're not a discussion site to talk about what is and isn't possible we're here to help you solve specific problems you're having building your world.

Comment: "Due to instinct" Is racism instinctual? Is it nature, nurture, or some of both? How am I supposed to answer the question "How complex can racism be?" What even is complexity here? Do you want me to build a fractal tree of ever-dividing racism and mathematically show the fractal continues forever? Someone can hate someone else, and someother can hate someone for hating someone else, ad naseaum. I don't see an objective answer to this. This sounds like something you and only you, the worldbuilder, can decide.

Comment: I am talking about how in like human behavior to discriminate, and things getting complex like how many governments in history have molded it into laws and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Racism is just within a species. So there is absolutely no reason racism and xenophobia can't exist between humans (it certainly does right now).

And at the same time [Speciesism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speciesism) or whatever you want to call it. We actually have that already as well and seem to have no issues applying them both.

Answer (score 1):

**Racism... indeed, all forms of bias and discrimination... are both natural and simple**

An old adage claims, "birds of a feather flock together." That adage exists because of a simple observation: humans like being around people who are just like they are. People who like playing video games like being around people who play video games. People who like walking through arboretums generally don't want to hang around people who like playing video games. We prefer to be around people who dress like us, act like us, think like us, believe like us, eat like us....

In other words, bias (and it's evil twin, racism) is simple. Humans are willing to use any reason (quite literally *any reason*) to hate someone. Skin color, ethnicity, gender... these just happen to be the really big ones that are reasonably easy to identify and do something about. (Can you imagine trying to pass a law that required all grocery stores to carry all types of potato chips in manufacture based on the belief that it's unfair to discriminate against anyone based on their preference of potato chip?)

And why do we do this? Well... if you favor religion, it's because God declared one group of people to be better than another. If you favor evolution, it's because we've had to climb the highly competitive evolutionary ladder for so long that we see everyone as competition to be despised. Either way, it's the way we're wired.<sup>1</sup>

So, when you ask how complicated it can get, it can get whomping complicated! But do we care?

And that's the point where you get to make some difficult worldbuilding decisions. *Does it matter?* People who swear a lot tend to prefer being around people who swear a lot, but for the most part, neither those who cuss a blue cloud nor those who don't really care that much. The choice to be with one or the other *isn't perceived as being unfair.* Oh, those who don't will continue to believe those who do are unwashed barbarians and those who do will continue to believe those who don't are pretentious snobs... but no one [will refuse to bake a cake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masterpiece_Cakeshop_v._Colorado_Civil_Rights_Commission) over it.

So... what's unfair to you?

People discriminate based on hair color and height and weight and occupation and how narrow their eyes are and whether or not they have a gap in their front teeth and what brand of shoes someone wears and what music they like and whether they prefer Marvel or DC Comics and what school they went to and how much they clean their house and what kind of job they did on their last project at work and what Dilbert cartoon they have on their office wall and millions (literally) of other things that cause hurt feelings.

Are you really trying to be that complex?

**Your job as a worldbuilder...**

You need to decide what falls under the mantle of "racism." It can be anything: like the color of clothes they wear. Because when an Elf wears Cerulean blue and not a Human (who, obviously, should be the only people allowed to wear Cerulean blue!), they're hated and the bias is racist.

Because birds of a feather will always flock together, unless said birds make a conscious choice to not act naturally. It's possible, just not always easy.

So, you tell us. What matters in your world?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *Please don't tell me that children are naturally loving and not discriminating. That's simply a bald-faced lie. I've watched far too many children fight over the silliest things and choose to favor themselves over another at nearly day one to believe that nonsense. They're just not old enough yet to use sophisticated methods to rationalize selfishness—like skin color.*</sub>